# How to handle namespace for Test.loadData method

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup, test-data, test.loaddata

I am trying to insert test data with Test.loadData for custom object with fields in my managed package. The problem is my developer org do not have a namespace and packaging org has it. How we can accomplish inserting a Custom field with a namespace dynamically.

The several workarounds are:

1. Insert 2 .csv, one with namespace and one without.
2. Global find and replace during deployment.

If there is any other dynamical way, I would appreciate it.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to move to sfdx-based development, where your (development) scratch orgs share the same namespace as your packaging org. My next comment is that you will hit issues with your current setup if you ever have to add Aura components since these have to include the namespace in their source when embedding components. Before moving to SFDX we actually leveraged Illuminated Cloud's "substitute" ability for deploy and retrieve, and ensured that each dev org had a registered namespace. With this namespaces, were mapped during deploy/retrieve as needed.

Comment: The Illuminated Cloud mechanism was basically a tidy "global find and replace" supported by automated querying of what the target namespace and configuration of the "official" namespace.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW we are on a process switching to sfdx, in a while I wanted to learn if we could accomplish it dynamically.